# Java applet display window out of browser

Tags: java, applet

I was wondering if it is possible to create a Java applet that displays a window that is not embedded into the web page, but is its own window, like a popup window. I would like not to use Java Web Start. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: sure it is possible. Why "no JWS"?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. I just used a jDialog and launched it from the applet.